# Gatling report description customization

Tags: gatling

The only global custom text on Gatling report is Simulation class name. It appears in the upper right corner of the report.

How can I put some custom message (short) without changing the name of the Simulation class?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As far as I know there are 3 ways of put some custom message to Gatling report

1. **Run description** param inside **gatling.conf** file, it is displayed at top part of report (next to report time and duration)

   ```
   gatling {
     core {
       runDescription = "Test description of report"
     }
   }
   ```

[image]

2. **Scenario name** - param of scenario in your test code, displayed on one of reports (Active Users along the Simulation)

   ```
   scenario("Scenario name")
     .exec(http("Action name").get("http://localhost"))
   ```

[image]

3. **Action name** - param of http in your test code, displayed on **Statistic** table

   ```
   scenario("Scenario name")
     .exec(http("Action name").get("http://localhost"))
   ```

[image]

Comment: how to customize the title of the report? default the class name with all lowercase

Comment: @XinMeng, I am in the same boat, did you find a solution to change default report header(its same as class name)?

Comment: @XinMeng did you find a way to customize the title?

Answer (score 0):

There's another way to get a short custom message into your report if you want to override it on a test-by-test basis, and don't want to edit the config file:

**We can use JVM args to override the defaults.**

So, to get a custom piece of text in the Run Information's Description field, we can define `gatling.core.runDescription` on our command line when we run the test:

```
mvn gatling:test -Dgatling.simulationClass=MySimulation -Dgatling.core.runDescription=My-custom-description-here
```

When we look at the generated report, we see our text in the **Description** field in the **Run Information** section, highlighted on the right of the image below:
[image: Custom Gatling Test Description]

*The caveat here, is that we can't have any spaces in the parameter value when running on Windows*. When we try using text with spaces in it, even when we wrap it in quotes (`-Dgatling.core.runDescription="My custom description here"`) the gatling-maven-plugin just ignores the parameter and logs this error:

`ERROR] System property value 'My custom description here' contains a whitespace and can't be propagated on Windows`

But if you're ok with this limitation, it's a useful workaround for getting some of your own information into the report!

And, in a similar way, we can change the name of the output directory that the report gets saved into by setting `-Dgatling.core.outputDirectoryBaseName=MyReportDirectory`.